# Rake gems:install says "could not find table", rake db:migrate says "required gems missing"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake

I just cloned a github repo on a fresh Ubuntu machine, running sqlite3 for all environments. `rake db:create` says development.sqlite3 already exists. `rake db:migrate` says I'm missing a bunch of required gems and should run `rake gems:install`. `rake gems:install`, of course, says it `Could not find table 'studies'`, which sounds to me like something `rake db:migrate` should fix.

I looked around the net and while lots of people have gotten 'could not find table' errors, they all got them from `rake db:migrate`, not `rake gems:install`. I'm suspecting it's an application-specific error, but still, any ideas would be appreciated.

PS: Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.8.

Answer (score 0):

You can always install separate gems with `gem install -r <gem name>` or `gem install -v=<gem version> -r <gem name>` command, not using rake.

Comment: I hesitated to do that because there were ~20 gems required :) But I did do it manually just now, and am now getting a different error. In environment.rb, formtastic v0.9.10 is required, but the only available version appears to be 1.2.3. Trying to fix that now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Rails 3 app? If so, you should run:

```
bundle install
```

Rails 3 uses Bundler instead of the rake tasks to manage gems. http://gembundler.com/

Comment: No, I use 2.3.8. Sorry, should have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running with the trace option? Might help pin down the failing gem:

`rake -t gems:install`